# SQLite3 + Rasperry Pi3 - 1st select on startup slow

Tags: sqlite, raspberry-pi3

I am using the pi to record video surveillance data in a single, but highly  populated table per camera.  The table consists of 3 columns - Timestamp, offset and frame length.  The video data is stored in a separate file on the filesystem.  My code is written in C.

Timestamp is the date/time for a video frame in the stream, offset is the fseek/ftell offsets into the streaming data file and frame length is the length of the frame.  Pretty self explanatory.  The primary and only index is on the timestamp column.

There is one database writer forked process per camera and there could be multiple forked read-only processes querying the database at any time.

These processes are created by socket listeners in the classic client/server architecture which accept video streams from other processes that manage the surveillance cameras and clients that query it.

When a read-only client connects, it selects the first row in the database for a selected camera.  For some reason, the select takes > 60 secs and subsequent selects on the same query are very snappy (much less than 1 sec).  I've debugged the code to determine this is the cause.

I have these pragma's configured both for the reader and writer forked processes and have tried greater and lesser values with minimal if any impact:

```
pragma busy_timeout=7000
pragma cache_size=-4096
pragma mmap_size=4194304
```

I am assuming the cause is due to populating the SQLite3 caches when a read-only client connects, but I'm not sure what else to try.

I've implemented my own write caching/buffering strategy to help prevent locks, which helped significantly, but it did not solve the delay at startup problem.

I've also split the table by weekday in an attempt to help control the table population size.  It seems once the population nears 100,000 rows, the problem starts occurring.  The population for a table can be around 2.5 million rows per day.

Here is the query:

```
sprintf(sql, "select * from %s_%s.VIDEO_FRAME where TIME_STAMP = "
                 "(select min(TIME_STAMP) from %s_%s.VIDEO_FRAME)",
        cam_name, day_of_week, cam_name, day_of_week);
```

(edit)

$ uname -a

```
Linux raspberrypi3 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

$ sqlite3

```
sqlite> .open Video_Camera_02__Belkin_NetCam__WED.db
sqlite> .tables VIDEO_FRAME
sqlite> .schema VIDEO_FRAME CREATE TABLE VIDEO_FRAME(TIME_STAMP UNSIGNED BIG INT NOT NULL,FRAME_OFFSET BIGINT, FRAME_LENGTH INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY(TIME_STAMP));
sqlite> explain query plan
   ...> select * from VIDEO_FRAME where TIME_STAMP = (select min(TIME_STAMP) from VIDEO_FRAME);
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE VIDEO_FRAME USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_VIDEO_FRAME_1 (TIME_STAMP=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1 1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE VIDEO_FRAME USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_VIDEO_FRAME_1 –
```

After some further troubleshooting, the culprit seems to be with the forked db writer process.  I tried starting the r/o clients with no streaming data being written and the select returned immediately.  I haven't found the root problem, but at least have isolated where it is coming from.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example and try to explain your problem in less words. I think this isn't about a Pi. It is about the operating system (which one?) you are running it with.

Comment: Show the table structure and the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html).

Comment: @buhtz -  $ uname -a
Linux raspberrypi3 4.1.19-v7+ #858 SMP Tue Mar 15 15:56:00 GMT 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux

Comment: @CL -  $ sqlite3
sqlite> .open Video_Camera_02__Belkin_NetCam__WED.db
sqlite> .tables
VIDEO_FRAME
sqlite> .schema VIDEO_FRAME
CREATE TABLE VIDEO_FRAME(TIME_STAMP UNSIGNED BIG INT NOT NULL,FRAME_OFFSET BIGINT, FRAME_LENGTH INTEGER,PRIMARY KEY(TIME_STAMP));
sqlite> explain query plan
   ...> select * from VIDEO_FRAME where TIME_STAMP = (select min(TIME_STAMP) from VIDEO_FRAME);
0|0|0|SEARCH TABLE VIDEO_FRAME USING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_VIDEO_FRAME_1 (TIME_STAMP=?)
0|0|0|EXECUTE SCALAR SUBQUERY 1
1|0|0|SEARCH TABLE VIDEO_FRAME USING COVERING INDEX sqlite_autoindex_VIDEO_FRAME_1

Comment: ... appologies for the sloppy looking comment.  First time poster to SO.

Comment: To edit the question, click "edit".

Comment: @doug4350 Please edit the question and provide that information in your question text and not as a comment.